# Ionic search popup with JSON value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Working on Ionic Search with Popup. It is working on

```
 $scope.selectables = [
    1, 2, 3 ];
```

But I want it to work on json

```
 $scope.countries = [
    {id: 1, text: 'USA', checked: false, icon: null}, 
    {id: 2, text: 'France', checked: false, icon: null}, 
    {id : 3, text: 'Japan', checked: true, icon: null}];
```

When I click on Select it button then Bind value USA, France, Japan.
I don't want to push value in Array.

The code I'm using can be found on codepen.io on the next link:

http://codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/Lbryzz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your options 
`options="selectables"` to `options="countries"` and  print it as `option.text` to display country name  and here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JjlZ1vYoewL2aIyNcbbc?p=preview) check it

```
<div class="item item-body">
          <button class="button button-positive" modal-select="" ng-model="someModel" options="countries" modal-title="Select " has-search="true">
            {{someModel.text}} 
            <div class="option">
              {{option.text}}
            </div>
          </button>
               <div class="item">
          someModel: {{someModel.text}} 
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. You did my max work, i want selected text to Display in replacement of Select it(Wit search Option) button.

Comment: please check now the same plunker

Comment: NO No . i am talking about to show it on button where Select it (with search) is showing.

Comment: check now the same

Comment: Like that but in default time means on page display it should show  "Chose Any"  then after selection it should show the value (which you have done).

Comment: updated and give all your requirements at once please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130200/discussion-between-sa-e-chowdary-and-anuj-gupta).